# Typings 'Cannot find module' - but only on some machines. Same project. Any ideas?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I've got the same project cloned on two machines. Both are running VS2015 and have Typings 1.8.6 installed. The working machine is Enterprise, the other is Professional... but I don't expect that matters.

Interestingly I get full intellisense support even without any triple slash references in individual files on the first machine. I think it picks up the triple slash file from a single file in scripts I called refs.d.ts (I suppose similar to a _references.js).

On the second machine all external imports throw 'Cannot find module ...'. This does not apply to internal imports from other project files.

So this line fails:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
```

But this line works:

```
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
```

It's like the working machine has some sort of global / enviornment settings the second is missing... but I've been trying to get the other machine working for days! Help much appreciated.

**What I've tried on the second machine:**

Triple slash in individual .ts files

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

Adjusting tsconfig.js:

- Removing node_modules from the exclude list
- Explicitly referencing the angular2 type definition file in the files array.
- ModuleResolution is 'Node'

Reinstalling typings on VS.

Comment: try checking in the browser developer tool network tab. and check if all your files are loaded. I landed upon a similar problem yesterday, the problem was that types was not able to access methods constructor from another exported class file. but I had complete intellisense. I took a lot of time to fidure it out eventully founf that the reference I was giving to the file was "typescript/SubFolder/myTpyscriptCompiled.js" while the file was  located in "typescript/myTpyscriptCompiled.js". @Vok

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think it might be a slightly different scenario though - the compiled typescript is fine and the project does run in the web. It's VS that seems to be having issues with the definition files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!!

**I upgraded from VS2015 to VS2015 Update 2.**

The machine that was already working was running Update 1.

This has been driving me nuts for days. Hope it saves someone else the headache!